# Show the first 2 and the last 3 lines from test.txt using "sed"

Tags: linux, bash, unix

UNIX

How can I show/print the first 2 and the last 3 lines from a txt file ex. test.txt?

**If someone can show me solutions using "cat" and "sed" commands!

Thank You!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I think this is a better, more intelligible solution than my original one... let's make a file with 1,000 lines:

```
seq 1000 > file
```

We can now count the lines with:

```
sed -n $= file
1000
```

In essence, we now want to delete lines 3 to 997, i.e.:

```
sed '3,997d' file
```

So we let `bash` do the maths of `1000-3` using an arithmetic context like `$((1000-3))` except that the `1000` is derived from another invocation of `sed` like the one above, i.e. `$(sed ...)`:

```
sed "3,$(($(sed -n $= file)-3))d" file
1
2
998
999
1000
```

---

**Original Answer**

This is extraordinarily ugly, how `sed` often looks, but works:

```
sed -ne '1,2p' YourFile;  sed -e :a -e '$q;N;4,$D;ba' YourFile
```

Comment: Yep! This is the answer that I was looking for! But can you please explain to me what does 

`-e :a -e '$q;N;4,$D;ba'` means?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

write a function to not to repeat the filename

```
$ function headtail { head -"$2" "$1"; tail -"$3" "$1"; }
$ headtail file 2 3
```

Comment: I need to use only "sed" or "cat" commands! I am not allowed to use other features!!